# Stored Procedure Output variable returning null when assigning value from itself

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

While trying `OUTPUT` variable, and assigning the variable with itself my proc returns null. The value is correctly assigning in the `OUTPUT` variable and works if I don't provide the optional output. Please check the below code

```
ALTER PROC [DBO].TEST (
    @IN NVARCHAR(10) ,
    @OUT NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'JAMES' OUTPUT)
AS
BEGIN
    SET @OUT = @OUT + '-' + @IN
    PRINT @OUT
END

---This Works
EXEC TEST 'BOND'
--OUTPUT : JASMES-BOND

---This doesn't Work
DECLARE @OUT1 NVARCHAR(MAX)
EXEC TEST 'BOND', @OUT1 OUTPUT
PRINT @OUT1
-- No Error, No Output
```

If I change the statement `SET @OUT = @OUT + '-' + @IN` to `SET @OUT =  '-' + @IN` the code gives output, but that's not my desired output. Please help me

Comment: or perhaps [Using Optional parameters when incoming value is null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43215375/using-optional-parameters-when-incoming-value-is-null)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect there are two factors that are leading to this situation.

1. Thats how concatenation works in SQL Server, `NULL` + anything = `NULL`. So you need to handle the `NULL` case.
2. And the default value you provide only works when you don't provide a parameter, as shown by your first example. But its ignored when you provide a parameter, even when its `NULL`, as shown by your second example.

For completeness I recommend handling both `@OUT` and `@IN` e.g.

```
SET @OUT = COALESCE(@OUT,'') + '-' + COALESCE(@IN,'');
```

Note: You can of course put something other than an empty string in for the `NULL` case.